# What security weekness(es) does my vino VNC server have?

Tags: security, authentication, vnc, snoop

I installed vino VNC server on Lubuntu 18.04, and configured and started my vino server according to https://askubuntu.com/a/530196/1471:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true # although fails, it doesn't matter
No such key “enabled”
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false    
$ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html says that

> VNC uses a random challenge-response system to provide the basic **authentication** that allows you to connect to a VNC server. This is reasonably secure; the password is not sent over the network. Once you are connected, however, **traffic between the viewer and the server** is unencrypted, and could be snooped by someone with access to the intervening network. We therefore recommend that if security is important to you, you 'tunnel' the VNC protocol through some more secure channel such as SSH.

Does vino VNC server authenticate clients using a challenge-response approach, instead of transferring password?

1. I could connect to the server at port 5900 from [RealVNC's VNC
   viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android&hl=en_US) on my Android phone within the same WIFI network, and  I
   was only asked to provide a password which I thought was the one used for logging into my Lubuntu.

   The quote at the beginning says that VNC uses challenge-response
   system, and doesn't transfer password, so does me having to provide
   a password mean that the VNC server transfers the password instead of using a challenge-response
   system? If it uses a challenge-response
   system, why do I have to provide a password?
2. In the following monitoring output message of the server,  I
   found the following suspicious clients [`46.101.184.149`](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/46.101.184.149),
   [`zg-0817a-64.stretchoid.com`](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/107.170.227.141),  [`196.52.43.118`](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/196.52.43.118), and
   [`scan-06.shadowserver.org`](https://www.abuseipdb.com/whois/216.218.206.67). Did they
   successfully connect to my vino VNC server, and were they authenticated?

   Since the quote at the
   beginning says that VNC uses challenge-response system, and doesn't
   transfer password, if the suspicious clients were authenticated, how could they find out the
   password? By testing every password to
   log in and being lucky?

   If the suspicious clients did not try to log in, but only snooped the traffic between the viewer and
   the server, isn't  it that the server should be unaware of these clients?

Thanks.

```
$ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server

(vino-server:32529): dbind-WARNING **: 19:44:12.185: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Autoprobing TCP port in (all) network interface
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Autoprobing selected port 5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing securityTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing securityTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing securityTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing authTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing securityTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Clearing authTypes
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
19/08/2018 07:44:12 PM Advertising security type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM Client Protocol Version 3.7
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM Advertising security type 18
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM Advertising security type 2
19/08/2018 07:44:17 PM Client returned security type 2

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 19:44:28.888: VNC authentication failure from 'android-c28b29b650f6548c.home'

19/08/2018 07:44:28 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 07:44:28 PM Client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home gone
19/08/2018 07:44:28 PM Statistics:
19/08/2018 07:44:28 PM   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM Client Protocol Version 3.7
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM Advertising security type 18
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM Advertising security type 2
19/08/2018 07:44:30 PM Client returned security type 2

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 19:44:40.531: Deferring authentication of 'android-c28b29b650f6548c.home' for 5 seconds

19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type 22
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type 21
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type 15
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding type -314
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM Pixel format for client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home:
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM   8 bpp, depth 6
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM Pixel format for client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home:
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
19/08/2018 07:44:45 PM no translation needed

Gtk-Message: 20:43:41.511: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: 20:43:44.339: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: 20:43:52.072: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:39:57.238: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM Client 46.101.184.149 gone
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM Statistics:
19/08/2018 10:39:57 PM   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
19/08/2018 10:43:41 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:43:41 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:43:41 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:43:41 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:43:41.812: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:43:47.449: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:43:47 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 10:47:27 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:47:27 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:47:27 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:47:27 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:47:27 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:47:27.692: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:47:32.452: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:47:32 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:51:12 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:51:12.833: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:51:18.448: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:51:18 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:54:58 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:54:58.339: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:55:03.449: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:55:03 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 10:58:43 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:58:43.756: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 22:58:49.448: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 10:58:49 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed

19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 11:02:28 PM Client Protocol Version 3.3

** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 23:02:28.345: Deferring authentication of '46.101.184.149' for 5 seconds


** (vino-server:32529): WARNING **: 23:02:33.449: VNC authentication failure from '46.101.184.149'

19/08/2018 11:02:33 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client zg-0817a-64.stretchoid.com
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM   other clients:
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      46.101.184.149
19/08/2018 11:30:51 PM      android-c28b29b650f6548c.home
19/08/2018 11:31:01 PM rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: client gone
19/08/2018 11:31:01 PM Client zg-0817a-64.stretchoid.com gone
19/08/2018 11:31:01 PM Statistics:
19/08/2018 11:31:01 PM   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
sendto: Network is unreachable
sendto: Network is unreachable
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: read: Connection reset by peer
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM Client android-c28b29b650f6548c.home gone
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM Statistics:
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM   key events received 32, pointer events 3932
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM   framebuffer updates 7016, rectangles 13714, bytes 270216867
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM     ZRLE rectangles 13714, bytes 270216867
20/08/2018 10:37:54 AM   raw bytes equivalent 538553044, compression ratio 1.993040
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 196.52.43.118
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM   other clients:
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Client Protocol Version 3.7
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Advertising security type 18
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Advertising security type 2
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Client returned security type 1
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM rfbAuthProcessSecurityTypeMessage: client returned unadvertised security type 1
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Client 196.52.43.118 gone
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM Statistics:
20/08/2018 02:15:10 PM   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client scan-06.shadowserver.org
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM   other clients:
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:26 PM      46.101.184.149
20/08/2018 02:31:28 PM rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: client gone
20/08/2018 02:31:28 PM Client scan-06.shadowserver.org gone
20/08/2018 02:31:28 PM Statistics:
20/08/2018 02:31:28 PM   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
```

Comment: When a log says `VNC authentication failure `, that generally means that the authentication failed.

Comment: @JennyD Thanks. Were those suspicious clients trying to authenticate themselves (by guessing password), and doing something else?

Comment: Everything we can know for sure about those clients in on the logs. So all we know is they tried to authenticate and failed.

Comment: @lain Is it correct that none of them successully authenticated and connected to my vino server?

Comment: I am not going to read your logs for you.

Comment: @la I read but only understand part of it

Answer (score 3):

> *"I could connect to the server at port 5900"*

That would explain why also other systems could , there is no software firewall restriction *on the server itself* that prevents connections to that port/service.

To explain how remote clients can connect, that depends on your  networking setup. If the Ubuntu server does not have an public internet IP-address, f.i. in a home situation you still may have set up port forwarding on your NAT router, configured it as a DMZ host or
both your router and vino server supports uPnP and your server instructed your router to open and forward the necessary ports.

> What kind of security problem does my VNC server have?

It accepts incoming internet connections.

And at first glance nothing more critical than that.

Comment: In this post, I would like to understand what has happened, more than finding a solution (I know that the most important thing to address is to prevent the VNC server from accessible from the Internet, but the following  incident happened several months ago, and right now the problem is gone away because I have moved and the local network has changed). So I'd appreciate if you could try to answer my individual questions in the post.

Comment: I have updated my post again, and try to make my questions clearer.